# GWT error while running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

When i'm trying to run gwt through eclipsc it showing the error like,

**

> Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use Try
>   overriding --address and/or --port.

**

Comment: You're trying to start when there is already another instance of `DevMode` running. Kill the old one and try again.

Comment: There is a RED square button in your Eclipse Console - keep pressing it till all your DevMode instances are killed and then start over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error like that means there is already a process running on that port, it might have crashed and may be dead thus it does not show up in your browser when you search it.
You need to stop that process, here are several commands

if you are running **linux** then run several lines in your console

get all applications running on port [need their pid]

```
sudo lsof -w -n -i tcp:8888
```

kill applications running on port

```
sudo kill -9 pidnumber
```

If **windows** then just:

Find the pid for the dead process that particular port

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

to kill the process

```
taskkill /F /PID <pid>
```